# Convert sRGB to Lab with convertColor?

Tags: r, rgb, lab-color-space

I'm trying to work with Lab colour, and need to do conversions from sRGB, ideally with R. I've just given [convertColor](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/convertColor.html) a go, and am a little confused. As a test, I'm converting the Macbeth ColorChecker swatches, but am not getting exactly the right values.

Example:

```
swatch1sRGB <- c(115,82,68)/255
swatch1Lab <- convertColor(swatch1sRGB, from="sRGB", to="Lab")
swatch1Lab
            L      a.x        b
[1,] 38.05293 11.86536 13.71442
```

Which is off the real values (37.986, 13.555, 14.059) by a reasonable margin of Macbeth ColorChecker values.

Comment: Aren't the sRGB values rounded, and therefore less precise than the Lab ones?

Comment: The sRGB values are rounded, but this doesn't solve the problem, because when you go the other way (Lab to sRGB), you'd round to 117, 81 and 67. Haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers you got with `convertColor` are correct. I reproduced the your results using `convert_colour` by `farver` package:

```
library(farver)
convert_colour(
  t(c(115, 82, 68)), 
  from = "rgb", 
  to = "lab")
```

The result is almost the same as in your example:

```
            l        a        b
[1,] 38.01682 11.79681 13.66437
```

Additionally [ColorHexa](https://www.colorhexa.com/735244) shows almost the same numbers as well (for CIE-LAB):

[image]

Comment: convertColor() is a function from grDevices and is not deprecated as far as I know.

Comment: Agree. Correct the answer.